# Fill a column with values by a percentage in R

Tags: r, fill

I need to fill out some values across 4 grouping variables, with a specific mean spread of occurrence. In particular I need column $A to contain a value of either 1 or 0. I need this for each instance of $B. This column is in turn grouped by categories in $C and $D $E.

```
A  B  C D E
0  1a a k 1
0  2a a u 1
1  3a a k 1
1  4a a u 1
0  5a a k 1
0  1a b u 2
1  2a b k 2
1  3a b u 2
1  4a b k 2
1  5a b u 2
```

So to clarify, I need 1’s to appear on a certain percentage of $B values across all the other groups. So eventually, I can have for example 50% of 1's when averaged across B, C, D and E.

I know this may not be entirely clear so please ask for clarification!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not understand what you want. How this value in column A is calculated on the second row for example? On the third row?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you want. Please create a complete reproducible example of your input, the expected output from the input and code that you have tried.